# Python data structure (dictionary)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I would like to extract the email from txt file, and count the appearance of emails.
But the output of emails are split into each letter.

The rest of coding aims to count the ouccurance.

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

di = {}
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '): #I forgot the space while the first trial
        line = line.rstrip()
        words = line.split()
        email = words[1]
        # print(email)
        for em in email:
            di[em] = di.get(em, 0) + 1
        print(di)
```

Unexpected output.

```
prolific_em = None
largest = -1
for v,k in di:
    if v > largest :
        largest = v
        prolific_em = k
print(prolific_em, largest)
```

```
6, 'b': 1, 'k': 1, 'y': 1, 'j': 2, 'w': 5, 'g': 4, 'v': 3}
{'s': 5, 't': 4, 'e': 28, 'p': 6, 'h': 8, 'n': 10, '.': 20, 'm': 11, 'a': 15, 'r': 12, 'q': 5, 'u': 34, 'd': 15, '@': 15, 'c': 14, 'z': 5, 'l': 7, 'o': 3, 'i': 27, 'b': 1, 'k': 2, 'y': 1, 'j': 2, 'w': 5, 'g': 5, 'v': 3}
{'s': 6, 't': 4, 'e': 28, 'p': 7, 'h': 8, 'n': 10, '.': 22, 'm': 16, 'a': 20, 'r': 13, 'q': 5, 'u': 34, 'd': 15, '@': 16, 'c': 16, 'z': 5, 'l': 9, 'o': 7, 'i': 28, 'b': 1, 'k': 3, 'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'w': 5, 'g': 7, 'v': 3}
{'s': 6, 't': 6, 'e': 28, 'p': 7, 'h': 9, 'n': 10, '.': 25, 'm': 16, 'a': 23, 'r': 14, 'q': 5, 'u': 35, 'd': 17, '@': 17, 'c': 18, 'z': 7, 'l': 9, 'o': 8, 'i': 30, 'b': 1, 'k': 3, 'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'w': 6, 'g': 7, 'v': 4}
{'s': 6, 't': 8, 'e': 28, 'p': 7, 'h': 10, 'n': 10, '.': 28, 'm': 16, 'a': 26, 'r': 15, 'q': 5, 'u': 36, 'd': 19, '@': 18, 'c': 20, 'z': 9, 'l': 9, 'o': 9, 'i': 32, 'b': 1, 'k': 3, 'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'w': 7, 'g': 7, 'v': 5}
{'s': 6, 't': 10, 'e': 28, 'p': 7, 'h': 11, 'n': 10, '.': 31, 'm': 16, 'a': 29, 'r': 16, 'q': 5, 'u': 37, 'd': 21, '@': 19, 'c': 22, 'z': 11, 'l': 9, 'o': 10, 'i': 34, 'b': 1, 'k': 3, 'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'w': 8, 'g': 7, 'v': 6}
{'s': 6, 't': 12, 'e': 28, 'p': 7, 'h': 12, 'n': 10, '.': 34, 'm': 16, 'a': 32, 'r': 17, 'q': 5, 'u': 38, 'd': 23, '@': 20, 'c': 24, 'z': 13, 'l': 9, 'o': 11, 'i': 36, 'b': 1, 'k': 3, 'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'w': 9, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 7, 't': 14, 'e': 30, 'p': 8, 'h': 13, 'n': 11, '.': 37, 'm': 17, 'a': 36, 'r': 19, 'q': 6, 'u': 40, 'd': 24, '@': 21, 'c': 26, 'z': 14, 'l': 9, 'o': 11, 'i': 36, 'b': 1, 'k': 3, 'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'w': 9, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 8, 't': 14, 'e': 35, 'p': 8, 'h': 13, 'n': 11, '.': 39, 'm': 18, 'a': 37, 'r': 20, 'q': 6, 'u': 42, 'd': 26, '@': 22, 'c': 26, 'z': 14, 'l': 11, 'o': 12, 'i': 38, 'b': 2, 'k': 4, 'y': 3, 'j': 2, 'w': 9, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 9, 't': 14, 'e': 40, 'p': 8, 'h': 13, 'n': 11, '.': 41, 'm': 19, 'a': 38, 'r': 21, 'q': 6, 'u': 44, 'd': 28, '@': 23, 'c': 26, 'z': 14, 'l': 13, 'o': 13, 'i': 40, 'b': 3, 'k': 5, 'y': 4, 'j': 2, 'w': 9, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 9, 't': 14, 'e': 45, 'p': 8, 'h': 13, 'n': 11, '.': 43, 'm': 20, 'a': 40, 'r': 23, 'q': 6, 'u': 45, 'd': 30, '@': 24, 'c': 26, 'z': 14, 'l': 14, 'o': 13, 'i': 41, 'b': 4, 'k': 6, 'y': 6, 'j': 2, 'w': 9, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 9, 't': 14, 'e': 47, 'p': 9, 'h': 13, 'n': 12, '.': 44, 'm': 20, 'a': 40, 'r': 23, 'q': 6, 'u': 48, 'd': 31, '@': 25, 'c': 27, 'z': 14, 'l': 14, 'o': 13, 'i': 43, 'b': 4, 'k': 6, 'y': 6, 'j': 2, 'w': 10, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 9, 't': 14, 'e': 49, 'p': 10, 'h': 13, 'n': 13, '.': 45, 'm': 20, 'a': 40, 'r': 23, 'q': 6, 'u': 51, 'd': 32, '@': 26, 'c': 28, 'z': 14, 'l': 14, 'o': 13, 'i': 45, 'b': 4, 'k': 6, 'y': 6, 'j': 2, 'w': 11, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
{'s': 9, 't': 14, 'e': 51, 'p': 11, 'h': 13, 'n': 14, '.': 46, 'm': 20, 'a': 40, 'r': 23, 'q': 6, 'u': 54, 'd': 33, '@': 27, 'c': 29, 'z': 14, 'l': 14, 'o': 13, 'i': 47, 'b': 4, 'k': 6, 'y': 6, 'j': 2, 'w': 12, 'g': 7, 'v': 7}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: If `email` is a string, `for em in email` iterates over characters of that string. What do you _want_ `for em in email` to iterate over instead?

Comment: @wwii I have changed the content. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not know that until I had tried a few times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `email` contain the email string, this `for em in email` iterates over the email letters, also it's better to handle files using `with` statement, so they close properly

```
di = {}
with open(name) as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('From '):  
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split()
            email = words[1]
            di[email] = di.get(email, 0) + 1
            print(di)
```

You can also use a `Conuter` that is made for counting things

```
from collections import Counter
di = Counter()
with open(name) as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('From '):
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split()
            email = words[1]
            di.update([email])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Mistakes

I made a few mistakes:

1. I did not store the extracted data into a list
2. I swapped the positions of key, value

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

di = {}
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '): #I forgot the space while the first trial
        line = line.rstrip()
        words = line.split()
        email = list()
        # it should use list to store the email otherwise the loop would treat extracted data as a massive string
        email.append(words[1])
        for em in email:
            di[em] = di.get(em, 0) + 1
        # print(di)
largest = -1
prolific_em = None
for k,v in di.items():
    if v > largest :
        largest = v
        prolific_em = k
print(prolific_em, largest)
```